# Pull / Push issues with Objective-Git

Tags: ios, swift, git, frameworks

I'm trying to pull and push a repository with an iOS App. I'm using Objective-Git and Swift.

I have made a simple class for pulling and pushing:

```
class Push: NSObject {
    func push(_ url: URL?, options: NSDictionary?, progress: ((UInt32, UInt32, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)?) -> Bool {
        let repo = try? GTRepository(url: url!)
        let branches = try! repo?.branches()
        let remotes = try! repo?.remoteNames()
        let remote = try? GTRemote(name: (remotes?[0])!, in: repo!)
        do {
            try repo?.pushBranches(branches!, to: remote!, withOptions: options as? [AnyHashable : Any], progress: progress)
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't push")
        }
        return true
    }

    func pull(_ url: URL?, options: NSDictionary?, progress: @escaping (UnsafePointer<git_transfer_progress>, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> ()) -> Bool {
        let repo = try? GTRepository(url: url!)
        let branches = try! repo?.branches()
        let remotes = try? repo?.remoteNames()
        let remote = try? GTRemote(name: remotes!![0], in: repo!)
        do {
            try repo?.pull(branches![0], from: remote!, withOptions: options as? [AnyHashable : Any], progress: progress)
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't pull")
        }

        return true
    }
    func creds(creds: GTCredential?) -> NSDictionary? {
        let gtcp = GTCredentialProvider { (type, a, b) -> GTCredential? in
            return creds
        }
        let d: NSDictionary = [
            "GTRepositoryRemoteOptionsCredentialProvider": gtcp
        ]
        return d
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to pull / push the repo with the correct credentials, it doesn't work

Any ideas to fix this? I couldn't find any example for doing such a thing, so maybe my code is completely wrong.

Comment: Print the parameters and options in the log. Compose the equivalent command and run it in the command line to see what error it throws.

Comment: @ElpieKay apparently, it's a merge conflict

Comment: I'm not familiar with Objective C or Objective-Git, but I guess Objective-Git provides error codes or exception types to describe errors. You can catch these errors and deal with them in the code, or just return the errors and leave them to the caller. It's not a good idea to always return true.